# Image not getting replaced in IsolatedStorage in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

I have stored few images in isolatedstorage and I am trying to replace them by using

```
 using (IsolatedStorageFile isStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()){
 if (isStore.FileExists(fileName)){
     isStore.DeleteFile(fileName);
 }
 using (IsolatedStorageFileStream targetStream = isStore.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)){
   // Initialize the buffer for 4KB disk pages.
   byte[] readBuffer = new byte[4096];
   int bytesRead = -1;
   // Copy the thumbnail to the local folder. 
   while ((bytesRead = e.ImageStream.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length)) > 0){
      targetStream.Write(readBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
      targetStream.Close();
   }
}
```

Now When I am trying to access the new file I end up seeing the old photo. the new photo is not replaced immediately.

But when I close the app and again fetch it I get the new photo. What is wrong?

Comment: If you get the right picture after restarting the app just by reading from the isolated storage, then it means the writing part is OK. The issue is on the reading part.

Comment: It sounds like something is getting cached somewhere. Can you provide a way to reproduce the behaviour you are seeing?

Comment: I am picking up the path from the targetStream.Name and binding it to an image control. this targetStream.Name is same as the original image and the new image does not get updated immidiately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using an ImageBrush to paint the background grid and was binding only the ImageSource of the ImageBrush. I guess this ImageBrush was not getting updated so instead of changing the source of the ImageBrush I created a new object of it and assigned it to Grid.Background. so now it works :)